# Length of the longest common sub sequence bottom up

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, strings, dynamic-programming

Could I get some feedback on this code? I included a test case as well.

This code computes the longest common sub sequence given paired data, it was not part of any challenge I just did it to learn about dp.

To my understanding it runs in \$\mathcal{O}(m*v)\$ where \$m\$ is length `str1` and \$v\$ len `str2`.

```
def lcs(word1, word2):

  x = len(word1)
  y = len(word2)
  return _lcs(word1, word2, x, y)

def _lcs(word1, word2, x, y):

  matrix = [[-1]*(x) for val in range (0,y)]

  for i in range(0, y):
    for j in range(0, x):

      if word1[j] == word2[i]:
        if i-1 < 0 or j-1 < 0:
          matrix[i][j] = 1 
        else:
          matrix[i][j] = 1 + matrix[i-1][j-1]

      else:
        val1 = 0
        val2 = 0
        if i-1 >= 0:
          val1 = matrix[i-1][j]
        if j-1 >= 0:
          val2 = matrix[i][j-1]
        matrix[i][j] = max(val1,val2)

  return matrix[y-1][x-1]

a = 'ABC'
b = 'ABCD'
print(lcs(a,b))
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I updated the main post, its not a challenge qn just one I did to learn something new, I would like feedback on code style/clarity/efficiency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x` and `y` are terrible variable names.  `length1` and `length2` would be better.

---

```
matrix = [[-1]*(x) for val in range (0,y)]
```

You are not using `val` in this list comprehension.  Convention is to use `_` for throw-away, variables needed for syntax reasons, but not actually used.

`0` is the default minimum in `range()` statements.  If you loop from `0` to some limit, you don't need to mention the `0`; you can just use `range(y)`.

You are never reading the `-1` value anywhere.  The value is always overwritten by another value before it is read.  To make this clearer, store `None` instead of `-1` in the matrix you are creating.

```
matrix = [ [None] * x  for _ in range(y) ]
```

---

Using `i-1 < 0` is an awkward way of writing `i == 0`.  Similarly, `i-1 >= 0` can be written simply as `i > 0`, or perhaps even `i`, since non-zero values are "Truthy".

---

The following is awkward and hard to understand.  6 statements, 4 assignments, two conditionals.  What does it do?  What does it mean?

```
    val1 = 0
    val2 = 0
    if i-1 >= 0:
      val1 = matrix[i-1][j]
    if j-1 >= 0:
      val2 = matrix[i][j-1]
```

Python has a `x if cond else y` trinary operator, which may help simplify and clarify the code.

```
    val1 = matrix[i-1][j] if i > 0 else 0
    val2 = matrix[i][j-1] if j > 0 else 0
```

That a lot more concise.  Two statements which look the similar; the differences should be clear, and it should be easier to understand what those differences mean.

```
  for i in range(y):
    for j in range(x):

      if word1[j] == word2[i]:
        matrix[i][j] = 1
        if i > 0 and j > 0:
          maxtrix[i][j] += matrix[i-1][j-1]

      else:
        val1 = matrix[i-1][j] if i > 0 else 0
        val2 = matrix[i][j-1] if j > 0 else 0
        matrix[i][j] = max(val1, val2)
```

---

The statement `return matrix[y-1][x-1]` returns the last column of the last row.  You don't actually need to know the dimensions of the matrix for this.  Simply `return matrix[-1][-1]`.

---

After you generate row 1, you no longer need row 0 of the matrix.  After you generate row 2, you no longer need row 1 of the matrix.  After you generate row 3, you no longer need row 2 of the matrix.  This means you could solve the problem in \$O(m)\$ memory, instead of \$O(m*v)\$ memory, by simply maintaining a `prev_row` and `next_row`, instead of an entire `matrix`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I learn a lot of new stuff.